# How do I prevent listview from scrolling to the top after using setAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview that switches between a few custom lists. I press a button to toggle between the different adapters in my listview but it jumps to the top of the listview. Is there a way I can stay in the same position on the screen as I switch between lists?

Answer (score 2):

don't use set adapter to update content , use notifyDatasetChanged istead

```
     if(listView.getAdapter()==null)
       listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    else{
       //update the adapter data

       myAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
```

that should work

Answer (score 0):

Use any of these 2:

```
1. Call getListView().setSelection(int iIndex);
2. Call getListView().smoothScrollToPosition();
```

Kindly let me know, if any of these works.